# How to extract B from ABA^T where A is not square

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

So I have this value in the form of ABA^T where A is 3 by 2 and B is 2 by 2.
I want to retrieve B, but since A is not square, it does not have an inverse. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can multiply on the left by $A^T$ and the right by $A$ which will result in $(A^TA) B (A^TA)$ now $A^TA$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix. Hope fully in ur case this is invertible.

Comment: I can't believe I missed something like that. Thank very much. Fortunately for me, it is invertible.